# SQL NUMBER FORMAT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The below SQL statement working for all the values like 40000,99 but for 0 the expected value is 0.00 but the result is .00

```
trim(to_char(value,'9,999,999.99')
```

Could you please suggest any possible solution for this,

The format should be **`x,xxx,xxx.xx`** and **0 should be displayed as 0.00**

Eg:40,000 , 1,250,000.00 , 0.00

Comment: Is there a reason you're SHOUTING AT US? What did we do to make you angry?

Comment: @KenWhite i am asking for help, and you are shouting here,
What did i do to make you so angry that you started shouting?
it seems you have so much arrogance and ego on your knowledge.
Is there any policy of stack overflow that only experts can post questions, an it not for Novice?

Comment: My point is that it's NOT POLITE TO SHOUT, and that includes SHOUTING THE TITLE OF YOUR QUESTION. There is absolutely no reason to type your question in ALL CAPS. It won't get you help any faster, it''s more difficult to read, and it's rude and annoying. Most people can understand that, and those that don't get a gentle reminder. There is a small group of people that have to have it specifically explained to them that it's NOT NICE TO SHOUT. It has nothing to do with expert/novice; it has to do with simple good manners. DON"T SHOUT WHEN POSTING HERE.

Comment: @KenWhite I am Sorry , i misunderstood what you meant to say.
I apologize , I will never use all Caps again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly indicate the zero before decimal point:

```
trim(to_char(value,'9,999,990.99')
```